# Connecting to my remote SqlServer database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, connection

Im currently making a wpf Windows Application, and it withdraws data from a database, so it is needed that I setup a connection to my remote servers SQL Server Database. Now i am getting a couple errors. When I first of all try to connect to my remote servers Sql Server using management studio, just to test if I could actually make a connection, I get the following error.

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occured during the login process. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

And ovcourse, I did try my best to do my research, and I found out a few things talking about allowing the SqlBrowser in firewall properties, done that...
allowing a connection to port 1433 and port 1434 through windows firewall, done that both.
Is there something Im missing or not doing?

Also it says "a connection was succcessfully established with the server" which means that It is able to connect, but something is going wrong somewhere. Also where it says "error occured during login process" could it simply mean I entered the wrong credentials?
I mean, when installing the SQLExpress I chose Windows Authentication so I never really got a username and password, So i just used the username and password for the Administrator account I use to connect to my server itself. Dont know It could have something to maybe just do with my login.
Could anyone please point me in the right direction as to why Im getting that error, even though I have enabled the TCP Connections and allowed SqlBrowser.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/07/26/678596.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad certificate-related error, probably caused by different operating systems/environmental differences. If this is for testing purposes I'd disable the certificate, or [you can configure it here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx#BKMK_managelocal) (which is probably a good idea if you're creating a real application and not just playing around with it).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think Ill just disable the certificate for now. How would I go about disabling it? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have just checked my SQL Server logs and I get this error:  Login failed for user 'MYPC/Administrator': Reason: Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication... That might be the problem... What does that error mean?

Comment: Nvm got it working by creating a new login and setting the login to be database owner

Answer (score 0):

Please run the sql service and agent service by creating new id and start the service with that like ea admin or any other.

The port error will continue to show even if you fix the port ,check telnet configuration and enabled/open port via it.

I had similar problems so i created a virtual server installed sql server2008 r2 and then started it worked fine.

There are possibilities of error and authentication problems since we reuse the server by formatting it .